# Search Google books api using RTK query in React

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

I am using RTK query with react for searching books using google api. I have one input search field where the user can enter the book name and after clicking on the search button it will fetch data from google api.

[image]

For now, I am setting `React` as the default search keyword but I want that to be blank by default. Below is the component and apiSlice code where the fetching happens.

```
// Main Component
const BookFinder = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('React');

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Row className='mt-5'>
          <h1>Book Finder</h1>
          <SearchBar {...{searchTerm, setSearchTerm}}/>
        </Row>
        <Row xs={2} md={4} className='g-5 mt-3'>
          <BookList {...{searchTerm}} />
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

I am using `react-bootstrap`, `font-awesome` libraries here.

```
// Search Bar
const SearchBar = ({ searchTerm, setSearchTerm }) => {
  const searchBar = useRef()

  return (
    <>
      <InputGroup className="mb-3 pt-3">
        <Form.Control
          placeholder={searchTerm}
          aria-label="Search"
          aria-describedby="search"
          ref={searchBar}
        />
      <Button variant="outline-primary" id="search" onClick={() => setSearchTerm(searchBar.current.value)}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMagnifyingGlass} />
      </Button>
      </InputGroup>
    </>
  );
}
```

import { useGetBooksQuery } from '../../services/bookSlice';

```
const BookList = ({ searchTerm }) => {
  const { data: books, isLoading, isSuccess, isError, error } = useGetBooksQuery(searchTerm)

  if(isLoading) {
    return (
      <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <strong>Loading...</strong>
        <div className="spinner-border" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  if(isError) {
    return <div>{error.toString()}</div>
  }

  if(isSuccess) {
    const { items } = books
    // return jsx code using books
  }
}
```

The above code is using `useGetBooksQuery` hook to get the data.

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

export const bookSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'bookApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1' }),
  tagTypes: ['Book'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getBooks: builder.query({
      query: (searchTerm) => `/volumes?q=${searchTerm}`,
      providesTags: ['Book'],
    }),
  }),
})

export const {
  useGetBooksQuery,
} = bookSlice
```

My problem is if I don't set the default value the api fails and gets an error. Is there any way I can omit the default value? So, the list will be empty the first time or will not call the google api when there is no value in text input. I think of using `mutation` instead of `query` but not sure if will it be the right thing to do. So use this platform to get some ideas to handle the above case. Thanks

Comment: Using [conditional fetching](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/conditional-fetching) will work here?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, i fell over it looking for something else, but its a fairly simple solution with RTK Query, so i thought i would post it regardles.

Use conditional fetching based on your search term:
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/conditional-fetching

In your case you would modify your usage of the hook like this:

```
const { data: books, isLoading, isSuccess, isError, error } = useGetBooksQuery(searchTerm, {skip: !searchTerm});
```